# Spring Integration: JMS Exception Handling

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration's own JMS Outbound Channel Adapter that is connected to Websphere MQ v7.1:

```
    <!-- plugging xyz channel into a JMS xyzQueue -->

    <channel id="xyzChannel"/>
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="xyzChannel"
                                  destination="xyzQueue"/>

    <!-- will listen on all packets matched, and forward them to a xyzChannel -->

    <beans:bean id="xyzSender" class="com.custom.XyzSender">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="messageChannel" ref="xyzChannel"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

In case MQ broker (its channel) goes down for a split of a second, the exception is logged:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2537;AMQ9558: The remote channel 'XYZ_CHANNEL' is not currently available ('MQRC_CHANNEL_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

From MQ docs these are possible reasons for this error:

- The channel is currently in stopped state.
- The channel has been stopped by a channel exit.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for this channel from this client.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for this channel.
- The queue manager has reached its maximum allowable limit for all channels.

However Spring Integration seems to eat it exception up, and in a split second after the MQ channel is available again, other messages get processed as nothing happened. Of course it results in a message drop, which is not an expected scenario.

What would be a way to handle this exception? There does not seem to be an error channel attribute on `jms:outbound-channel-adapter`.

Comment: You need to show your full Spring Integration configuration (especially showing if you have an error-channel on the inbound endpoint), and what the error flow on that channel does.

Comment: updated with more configuration. the error flow should be very simple: "exception? => blow up". I don't need to reply with error, or anything of that sort. There is no Spring Integration on the other side of the MQ.

Comment: The reason I said FULL Spring Integration configuration is because the error-channel goes on whatever starts the flow and I need to see what you are doing there.

I don't know what's upstream of xyzChannel and I can't speculate.

Comment: that is pretty much the whole SI config, since `xyzChannel` is just injected into a bean that receives something over TCP/IP (not using SI) and calls `.send` on it once it has data to send over.

Comment: In that case, the exception will be thrown to the calling thread (the one that calls send() ). Generally it is not good practice to inject channels directly - ties your application to the framework - consider using a Messaging Gateway instead (with an error-channel) http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

Comment: right, I would expect the exception being thrown from the `send` method, however it does not seem to be (gets eaten somewhere). The reason `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` is not used is because we can't handle another proxy in the mix (performance). In any case, I switched to `JmsTemplate`, so no more issues. Thanks for jumping in Gary.

Comment: Well, I don't believe it's SI that eating the exception; I just ran a test and the caller got the exception as expected. 

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#0]
...

 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
 at org.springframework.integration.samples.jms.ChannelAdapterDemo.main(ChannelAdapterDemo.java:48)